# Real Time Location System using MongoDB, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, websocket, real-time

Hello Everyone i am working on MERN Stack since last 2 Years. i am having a question which is related to "REAL TIME LOCATION SYSTEM" and my Question is

**Q1:-** My client has 1000 devices which is implemented on some cars, forklift or some of in the human hand , and he want to track every single device location and see on his display Real-Time.  My question is how to track all device information at a time . I am using MongoDB for database. I plan to solve this problem using develop a API with the combination of the hardware SDK which will trigger after every 3-5 sec. but can this is the best approach that the data first go to the DB then by using web socket its displayed. can its not delayed ? and if not then what is the best ideal way to achieve this?

**Q2:-** i have calculated the data size which is generated by all device is approx 400-500GB every month & i have to take record of last 3 month data. Now as i am using mongoDB as DB
so how i can minimize the size and maintain High Scale Availability?

**Q3:-** And the most important one is Client want to deploy the APP Locally. I am using nodejs and Express for creating Server in the back-end development . If anyone know any way how to store real time data please help?

Answer (score 0):

At first, I recommend you use Redis if it's possible.
In redis you can define your users as a Key and their locations as a Value, and show it in admin dashboard by subscribing on your Keys.

```
https://redis.io/topics/notifications
```

For archiving data, you can use MongoDB or Any SQL databases such as Postgres.
For MongoDB you can use sharding Data for partitioning data, it can improve your performances incredibly

```
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/
```

if your data is not Json structure base, you can use Posgress SQL or MySQL too and use Partition Table